# A contour integration approach for $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{4}+2 x^{2} \cos 2 a+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} \, d x$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, complex-integration, trigonometric-integrals

**Background**

In this week, I am tackling the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1-x+x^{2}\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x$$
and found that a general formula below in [my post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4512956/732917), $$
\begin{aligned}
J(a)= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+2 x \sin a+x^{2}\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x=& \pi\left(\ln \left(2 \cos \frac{a}{2}\right)\right)+|a| \ln \left(\tan \frac{|a|}{2}\right)-2 \operatorname{sgn} (a) \int_{0}^{\frac{|a|}{2}} \ln (\tan x) d x
\end{aligned}
$$

by which, I found a decent formula for the quartic one, $$
\boxed{I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{4}+2 x^{2} \cos 2 a+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x=2 \pi \ln \left(2 \cos \frac{a}{2}\right)}
$$

**Proof:**
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(a)&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{4}+2 x^{2} \cos 2 a+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left[\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{2}+2 x^{2}(\cos 2 a-1)+1\right]}{1+x^{2}} d x\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left[\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{2}-4 x^{2} \sin ^{2} a\right]}{1+x^{2}} d x\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{2}+2 x \sin a+1\right)}{1+x^{2}}+\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{2}-2 x \sin a+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x\\& =J\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)+J\left(-\frac{a}{2}\right)\\& =2 \pi \ln \left(2 \cos \frac{a}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

For examples:
$$
K=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{4}+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x= I\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=2 \pi \ln \left(2 \cos \frac{\pi}{8}\right)= \pi \ln (2+\sqrt{2})
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
L=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{4}+x^{2}+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x&=I\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=2 \pi \ln \left(2 \cos \frac{\pi}{12}\right)=\pi\ln (2+\sqrt{3})
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
M=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{4}-x^{2}+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x&=I\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=2 \pi \ln \left(2 \cos \frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\pi\ln 3
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
N=&\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{8}+x^{4}+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} dx = L+M=\pi \ln (6+3 \sqrt{3})
\end{aligned}
$$
Last but not least,

$$
\boxed{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{4}+b x^{2}+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x = 2 \pi \ln \left[2 \cos \left(\frac{1}{4} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)\right)\right]}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{8}+1\right)}{1+x^{2}}=& \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{4}+\sqrt{2} x+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x +\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{4}-\sqrt{2} x+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x \\
=& 2 \pi \ln \left[2 \cos \frac{1}{4} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right] +2 \pi \ln \left[2 \cos \frac{1}{4} \cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right] \\
=& 2 \pi \ln \left(2 \cos \frac{\pi}{16}\right)+2 \pi \ln \left(2 \cos \frac{3 \pi}{16}\right)\\
=& 2 \pi \ln \left(2^2 \cos \frac{\pi}{16} \cos \frac{3 \pi}{16}\right)\\=& 2 \pi \ln (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})
\end{aligned}
$$

**Eager to know whether it can be proved by contour integration.**

Your help and solutions are highly appreciated!

Comment: If one wanted to, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cos%28acos%28x%29%2F4%29+vs+%28-1%29%5E%281%2F8%29%2F%282+%28i+x+%2B+sqrt%281+-+x%5E2%29%29%5E%281%2F4%29%29+-+1%2F2+%28-1%29%5E%287%2F8%29+%28i+x+%2B+sqrt%281+-+x%5E2%29%29%5E%281%2F4%29) is an evaluation of $\cos\left(\frac14\cos^{-1}(x)\right)$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: For your contour integration, since the integrand is even, the integral will be half of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$, which is $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R}^R$, which is the portion on the real line of a contour that can be closed with a semicircle in the upper half-plane. Show that the integral over the semi-circle goes to $0$ as $R \to 0$ (it does), then all you have to do is take the residues of the singularities in the upper half plane (there are two, and two more in the lower half plane you can ignore).

Comment: Thank you for your good suggestion!

Comment: @PaulSinclair Are you sure? Since substituting $-x$ gives $\frac{\ln(1+x+x^2)}{x^2+1}$

Comment: @KamalSaleh - I was referring to the integral the OP was actually asking about (in the box), not the one they off-handedly mentioned working on in the prologue to their question.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Oh, I see now. This is an even function.

Comment: @KamalSaleh - It is a bit confusing, the way it is stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $0 \le  a < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Using the principal branch of the logarithm, we have  $$ \begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x^{4}+2x^{2}\cos(2a)+1)}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x^{4}+2x^{2}\cos(2a)+1)}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx  \\ &=   \Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x^{2}+e^{2ia})}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \\ &=  \Re \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left((x+ie^{ia})(x-ie^{ia}) \right)}{1+x^{2}} \,  \mathrm dx \\ &=  \Re \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x+ie^{ia})}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x-ie^{ia})}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \right) \\ &=  \Re \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm dx + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ g(x) \, \mathrm dx \right).  \end{align} $$

(The identity $\ln(z_{1}z_{2}) = \ln(z_{1}) + \ln(z_{2})$ holds if $-\pi < \arg(z_{1}) +\arg (z_{2})  \le \pi$).

The function $f(z)$ has has a branch cut in the lower half-plane, while the function $g(z)$ has a branch cut in the upper half-plane.

Therefore, we'll integrate $f(z)$ counterclockwise around a closed semicircular contour in the upper half-plane, and we'll integrate $g(z)$ clockwise around a closed semicircular contour in the lower half-plane.

We get $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x^{4}+2x^{2}\cos(2a)+1)}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx &=  \Re \, 2 \pi i \left( \operatorname{Res}[f(z), i] - \operatorname{Res}[g(z), -i] \right)  \\ &=  \Re \, 2 \pi i\left(\frac{\ln(i+ie^{ia})}{2i} - \frac{\ln(-i-ie^{ia})}{-2i} \right) \\ &= \pi \left(\frac{1}{2} \, \ln \left(2+2 \cos(a) \right) + \frac{1}{2} \, \ln \left(2+2 \cos(a) \right)\right) \\ &= \pi \ln \left(4 \cos^{2} \left(\frac{a}{2} \right) \right) \\ &= 2 \pi \ln \left(2 \cos \left(\frac{a}{2} \right) \right). \end{align}$$

Comment: Wonderful use of upper and lower semi-circle on quadratic to which the given quartic is reduced via $\ln(a^2+b^2)=2Re(\ln(a+bi))$! Thank you very much.

Comment: But, maybe it is possible to compute with 4 parts...

Answer (score 2):

There are four ugly branch cuts so lets try Feynman's trick. Let $I(a)$ be the given integral. Then,
$$I'(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{-4x^2\sin(2a)}{(1+x^2)(x^4+2x^2\cos2a+1)}dx.$$
By means of the contour integral around the closed counter-clockwise semicircular contour and the residue theorem we get
$$\begin{align}
I'(a)&=\pi i(Res_{z=\Large i}f(z)+Res_{\Large z=ie^{ai}}f(z)+Res_{\Large z=ie^{-ai}}f(z))\\
&=\pi i(-i\cot a+\frac{e^{ai}}{1-e^{2ai}}-\frac{e^{-ai}}{1-e^{-2ai}})\\
&=-\pi\tan\frac a2.
\end{align}$$
Hence, $I(a)=2\pi\ln(\cos\frac a2)+c.$ But, $c=I(0)=\int_0^\infty\frac{2\ln(x^2+1)}{x^2+1}dx=2\pi\ln2.$ Hence, $I(a)=2\pi\ln(2\cos\frac a2).$

Comment: A good demonstration of Feynman’s trick.  Thank you very much.